# Getting Div tag to extend to the bottom of the Page w/out covering elements already on the page

Tags: html, css

I have tried absolute to my footer to stay on the bottom of the page but it covers up the elements that are already at the bottom instead of going underneath them.  Fixed does the similar thing except if the page is longer it will cover up elements in the center of the page. I literally just want the backgound color of my div to extend to the bottom of the page and have my logo and text stay in between the div at a set height. Here's what I've got.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
<title>

</title>

<div class="heading">
<img src="Images/Redbird.gif"   alt="Redbird" style="float:left; padding-left:15px; padding-top:15px; width:150px;height:90px">

<form>
    Search:
    <input type="search" name="Search" style="float:right;">
</form> 
<br></br>
<button type="button" id="Login">Login</button>
<button type="button" id="Login">Create New Account</button>
<h1>Technology Blog</h1>
<a href="index.html">
<img src="Images/House.png" alt="Home" style="width:35px; height:35px;">
</a>
</div>

<div class="table">
<table style+"width:100%">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="phones.html">Phones & Tablets</a></td>
        <td>Computers & Laptops</td>
        <td>Internships</td>
        <td>Troubleshooting</td>
        <td>Product Ratings & Reviews</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</head>

<body>
<div class="Welcome">
<h2>Welcome</h2>
<p>Welcome to Illinois State University's Technology Blog.  Here you can view and post questions, answers, reviews, and other information that is related to technology.  This website is for Illinois State University Students ONLY! You must sign in or create an account to view or post on this website.</p>
</div>
<div class="Slideshow">
<img src="Images/DellComps.jpg" alt="Computers" style="width: 397px; height: 298px">
</div>

</body>

<div class="Footer">

<img src="Images/Seal.png" alt="ISU Seal" style="width: 40px; height: 40px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-top: 10px">

Copyright 2014 @ TEC 319 Group <br/> Illinois Sate University
</div>

</html>
```

heres the CSS. I only need to edit the .Footer tag i believe

```
html{
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}
h1{
text-align: center;
font-family: impact;
font-style: italic;
}

.heading{
background-color: #CA0000;
height:150px;
}
td{
border:5px solid black;
text-align:center;
background-color:#790000;
color:white;
padding:10px;
font-family: helvetica;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 15px;
}
table{
width:100%
}
.table{
background-color:black;
height:53px;
}
form{
float:right;
}
button{
float:right;
}
.Slideshow img{
display: block;
position: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.Footer img{
display: block;
position: center;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
.Footer{
margin-top: 40px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #D8D8D8;
padding-bottom: 20px;
width: 100%;
}


.Preview td{
display: block;
text-align: left;
color: black;
background-color: white;

}
.Blog td{
display: block;
text-align: left;
color: black;
background-color: white;
border: 0px;

}
.newPost h2{
display: block;
position: center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right: auto;
vertical-align: middle;
color: white;
background-color: #790000;
border: 5px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
}
h3 {
color: white;
background-color: #790000;
border: 5px solid black;

}
h4{
text-align: left;
font-size: 14pt;
color:#790000
}
.back h2{
display: block;
position: left;
border:5px solid black;
background-color:#790000;
color:white;
padding:10px;
font-family: helvetica;
font-style: italic;
font-size: 15px;
width: 100px;
}

form.comment{
float:left;
size
}
a.blogTitle:link {
color: #790000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.blogTitle:visited{
color: #790000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.blogTitle:active{
color: #790000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a.blogTitle:hover{
color: #CA0000;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:link {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:active{
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover{
color: #CA0000;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the footer always visible? Or do you want it below everything in the page body? Those are two different cases requiring different answers.

Comment: Answer below. @tator

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the footer position to `relative` to have it respect other elements on the page. Both `absolute` and `fixed` remove the element from the page flow, which causes overlapping.

## [Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/zfuKD)

Change `position:relative` to `fixed` in the demo CSS and then uncomment `bottom` to see the difference. You can also play with `height` on the body tag to see how behavior changes.

```
<div id="content">
  <p>Content</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
  <p>Footer stuff</p>
</div>  

body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#content {
  height:1200px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:#eee;
  position:relative;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid black;
}
#footer {
  width:100px;
  position:relative;
  /* bottom:0; */
  background-color:#eee;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: There is still white space between the .Footer div tag and the bottom of the page.

Comment: Didn't mention that in your question. CodePen demo is updated. To remove whitespace around elements, you have to set `body { margin:0; padding:0 }` as well.

Comment: I appreciate your help but none of this is working the way I want it to. I'll have to ask my professor. Thanks for taking the time out again though, much appreciated!

Comment: I just noticed your `footer` tag is outside the document body. You need to clean up your HTML. The `</body>` should follow all of your content.